# String Interpolation in Swift URL Initializer Throwing Error

Tags: swift, url

I have the following code:

```
source.id = "abc-news"

let articlesBySourceURL = URL(string: "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=\(source.id)&apiKey=somekeyhere")!
```

It always throw the following error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional

Am I missing something?

Comment: Obviously the crash is from force-unwrapping `URL` when `URL(string:)` is returning `nil`. And of course this means that your final string isn't a valid URL.

Comment: Don't do swift URL string interpolation. Don't call `URL(string:)`. Form the URL properly using URLComponents. That's what it's for.

Comment: "Am I missing something?" Knowledge of Swift?

Comment: Thanks! but my \(source.id) is not null

Comment: Try building the string first then printing it to the console before you hand it off to your initializer. Does it look like a valid URL?

Comment: Perfect @jefflovejapan Thanks! Yes you are correct. It was printing Optional() something. If you write that as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try building the string first then printing it to the console before you hand it off to your initializer. Does it look like a valid URL?